# Installation of package ' ' had non-zero exit (tidyverse R - linux mint)

Tags: installation, linux-mint, r, rstudio

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

but R is keep showing me these messages:

```
1: In install.packages("tidyverse"):
installation of package 'openssl' had non-zero exit
installation of package 'httr' had non-zero exti
installation of package 'rvest' had non-zero exit
installation of package 'tidyverse' had non-zero exit
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to add the CRAN2deb4ubuntu PPA. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ for details. Then you can install using

```
sudo apt install r-cran-tidyverse
```

The alternative is to see why the install is failing and to fix it. For example, openssl is likely to be failing because you haven't installed OpenSSL. You can do so using

```
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev
```

There may also be other dependencies you need to install.